# Change column width in QTableView with mouse

Tags: c++, qt

I need behaviour in `QTableView` for changing of column width not only with help of `QHeaderView`, but directly on `QTableView` area itself. It will be good if I can set cursor pointer between cells in `QTableView` area and change the column width with "click and drag" on `QTableView` area itself.

Comment: I'll normally recommend to keep the behavior as it is because users are used to an excel-like behavior. That becomes sort of de facto standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a partial answer, showing how to access column separators

```
/** sense mouse position */
bool FreezeTableWidget::eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove) {
        QMouseEvent *m = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        QPoint p = m->pos();
        QRect r = visualRect(indexAt(p));
        if (abs(p.x() - r.x()) < 3) // || abs(p.x() - r.right()) < 3)
            setCursor(Qt::SplitHCursor);
        else
            unsetCursor();
    }
    return false;
}
```

eventFilter is a virtual function, but you must register it to get it called. I added in the FreezeTableWidget constructor:

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);
```

*edit*: about position check, the suggestion from evilruff also works (albeit the computational efficiency argument is irrilevant), but in general I think that you could try an alternative, more general approach: namely to use the horizontalHeader item as a surrogate handler, because there we already have all the required, working, logic.

If you like to experiment with (and learn about) these GUI details, try to shift the vertical mouse position, and give the event to the header... I think it could work, and will be simpler than tracking the state by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't see anything wrong with such behaviour. Especially for read-only table views where it could be really convenient.

Fastest way to implement this to install event handler which will catch mouse events and issue resize commands. Obviously you will have to calculate manually if mouse is over/around column separator.

UPD: to get an idea if cursor is around vertical axes you can use following method:

```
/* Returns the x-coordinate in contents coordinates of the given column. */
int x = tableView->columnViewportPosition(int column);
```

mouse event will give you mouse position and then you can easily see if it matches any of column axes.

UPD2: I would even implement it in a bit more complicated way to handle mousemove together with header resize/scroll events within one eventHandler...  to cache column positions in a sorted list, to optimise time spent in mousemove handler.. so, you will get binary search and distance check.. but its of course depends how heavy is interface in general..

Comment: Then the question is: how do you know when the mouse is over a column separator ? I searched a lot, and not yet found it.

Comment: Well, you have mouse position, you know width of individual columns and you know and offset, so that's just a cycle checking if mouse is around any vertical axis

Comment: But do you know how Qt handles such elements, or you are simply talking generic ? It's obvious that we have a mouse, columns, coordinates... The tricky part is how to get such information...

Comment: I have updated my answer. visualRect is more 'costly' function in respect to the performance, because it checks both axes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all!

Below is my result with source code, that implement behaviour like in the question (little bit dirty, but with general idea):

```
#define DELTA_SPLIT 4
static bMouseBetweenCols= false;
static int nResizeColumn= -1;

void CHeaderTableView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    QMouseEvent *m = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    QPoint p = m->pos();
    QRect r = visualRect(indexAt(p));

    if (bMouseBetweenCols && nResizeColumn != -1)
    {
        QTableView* pT= dynamic_cast<QTableView*>(parent());
        if (pT)
        {
            Q_ASSERT(pT->horizontalHeader());

            int nMinSectionSize= pT->horizontalHeader()->minimumSectionSize();
            int nSectionSize= p.x() - columnViewportPosition(nResizeColumn);

            if (nSectionSize >= nMinSectionSize)
            {
                pT->horizontalHeader()->resizeSection(nResizeColumn, nSectionSize);
            }
        }
    }

    if (    abs(p.x() - r.right()) <= DELTA_SPLIT
        ||  abs(p.x() -  r.left()) <= DELTA_SPLIT)
    {
        setCursor(Qt::SplitHCursor);

        event->ignore();
        return;
    }
    else
        unsetCursor();

    QTableView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}

void CHeaderTableView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMouseEvent *m = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    QPoint p = m->pos();
    QRect r = visualRect(indexAt(p));

    if (    abs(p.x() - r.right()) <= DELTA_SPLIT
        ||  abs(p.x() -  r.left()) <= DELTA_SPLIT)
    {
        QTableView* pT= dynamic_cast<QTableView*>(parent());
        if (pT)
        {
            nResizeColumn= pT->horizontalHeader()->visualIndex(indexAt(p).column());

            if (abs(p.x() - r.left()) <= DELTA_SPLIT) { nResizeColumn--; }

            nResizeColumn= pT->horizontalHeader()->logicalIndex(nResizeColumn);

            if (nResizeColumn >= 0)
                bMouseBetweenCols= true;

            event->ignore();
            return;
        }
    }

    QTableView::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void CHeaderTableView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMouseEvent *m = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    QPoint p = m->pos();
    QRect r = visualRect(indexAt(p));

    if (    abs(p.x() - r.right()) <= DELTA_SPLIT
        ||  abs(p.x() -  r.left()) <= DELTA_SPLIT)
    {
        bMouseBetweenCols= false;
        nResizeColumn= -1;

        event->ignore();
        return;
    }

    bMouseBetweenCols= false;
    nResizeColumn= -1;

    QTableView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}

void CHeaderTableView::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMouseEvent *m = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
    QPoint p = m->pos();
    QRect r = visualRect(indexAt(p));

    if (    abs(p.x() - r.right()) <= DELTA_SPLIT
        ||  abs(p.x() -  r.left()) <= DELTA_SPLIT)
    {
        QTableView* pT= dynamic_cast<QTableView*>(parent());
        if (pT)
        {
            int nDblClickColumn= pT->horizontalHeader()->visualIndex(indexAt(p).column());

            if (abs(p.x() - r.left()) <= DELTA_SPLIT) { nDblClickColumn--; }

            nDblClickColumn= pT->horizontalHeader()->logicalIndex(nDblClickColumn);
            pT->resizeColumnToContents(nDblClickColumn);
        }

        event->ignore();
        return;
    }

    QTableView::mouseDoubleClickEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Little bit improvement for situations, when some columns can be moved between them (logical and visual column index is not equal).

Comment: Nikolai, I'm glad you picked and built on my hint, but I would advice that using static global variables to track state in a GUI is calling for trouble...